# How to ignore specific values while looping

Tags: javascript, swift

I want to convert this javascript to swift that is meant to solve a coding test. The algo counts up to a number and skips specific numbers while looping.

A hotel has 300 rooms each numbered with a three-digit   number beginning at 001. However the digits 2 and 5 are not used anywhere in any room numbers. What is the room number for the 100th room?

javascript

```
var currentNumber = 1, var n = 0;
while (currentNumber <= 100) {
    n++;
    if (n.toString().search(/[25]/) == -1)
    currentNumber++
    }
    console.log(n);
```

Swift attempt

```
var currentRoom = 1
var n = 0

while currentRoom <= 100 {
    n += 1
    if n. // don't know the Swift equivalent methods.
}
```

Edit: I was able to code another solution in addition to the accepted answer using Swift's repeat syntax.

```
var roomNumber = 1, x = 0
repeat {
    x += 1
    if String(x).contains("2") || String(x).contains("5")  {
        continue
    }
    roomNumber += 1

} while roomNumber <= 100
print(x)
```

Comment: This question has been edited several times to satisfy the users who put it on hold. The title clearly explains the goal. The question has a positive vote. The question includes a description of the problem that needs to be solved. The question has a perfect accepted answer. An additional answer has even been added to the question. So it seems like the hold is now meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var currentRoomNo = 1
var n = 0
while currentRoomNo <= 100 {
    n += 1
    if String(n).contains("2") || String(n).contains("5")  {
       continue
    }
    currentRoomNo += 1
    }
print(n)
```

Comment: Thank you providing an actual answer where I can study the Swift syntax and work it out. p.s. Is there a more functional approach?

Comment: Okay , yeah, my bad :P